# add(inject) a condition in every find query in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to add(inject) a condition to all of my find-like queries, by find-like queries I mean queries that have find in them, like `find`, `findOne`, `findOneAndUpdate`, `findByIdAndUpdate` and ...

for example, I have this query in my code:

```
model.findOne({a: 1})
```

but I want this query to run:

```
model.findOne({a: 1, b: 2})
```

and my purpose is that `{b:2}` be in every query so I don't want to be typing it in every single query.

I tried to use `schema.pre('find', function(){})` hook but I failed.

I used the hook like this:

```
schema.pre('find', async function f(){
    const query = Object.assign({}, { b: 2}, this.getQuery())
    this.setOptions(query)
    console.log(this.getQuery())
})
```

but the console.log shows that the query has not changed.

Comment: and also `this.setQuery(query)` throws this error: `this.setQuery is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findOne` example:

```
AuthorSchema.pre('findOne', function(next) {
  // Put your logic here for whatever you want to "decorate" ...
  let conditions = this.getQuery() // get the current conditions
  conditions._id = "5b80f96e9fceda195ba853af" // Change to whatever you want
  this._conditions = conditions  // Set the new conditions
  next();
});
```

Would make this:

```
var result = Author.findOne({_id: "5b7fa665844b5ebfad064b1c" })
.populate("books")
.exec()
```

Return actually the record with ObjectId of `5b80f96e9fceda195ba853af`

Comment: what if I want all find-like queries to fire the hook?

Comment: Updated the answer for `fineOne` ... Confused ... your question stated that you wanted for `every` query to decorate the input with `{ b: 2}` ... is this another question?

Comment: no I said at first that I wanted to inject a condition to all find-like queries like findOneAndUpdate, findOne, findByIdAndUpdate and ...

Comment: Gotcha. Do not think there is one hook to rule them all type thing here ...

Comment: this actually solved part of my problem, but that way of directly changing `this._conditions_.b` is somehow, as you say, harsh! is there any better way for doing this?

Comment: I updated to something less harsh but overall I do not see any other way at that stage nor I see less harsh method of doing it.